# How can I save user input in my chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, user-input

I'm making a Chrome countdown clock extension and I want to save the user input in javascript, is there anyway to do this?

here is the code,

```
var userInput = prompt ("Enter Your Date");
var countDownDate = new Date(userInput).getTime();
```

Comment: You could also use [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage).

Comment: Actually, I take that back.  That's a better idea for an extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can use chrome.storage function from google libraries.
chrome.storage.sync to syncronise the data with your google account
chrome.storage.local for not syncronising.
set is used to set the variables
get is used to take the variables.

to set the variable in one page:

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({'nameInTheStorage' : jsVariables}, function(){
    if(chrome.runtime.error){
        console.log("Error.");
    }
});
```

to get the variables in another page:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get('nameInTheStorage', function(items){
    if(!chrome.runtime.error){
        //do what you want to do with the data
        var x = items.nameInTheStorage;
    }
}
```